# Clarification of objects using questions

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances

When I want to ask whether or not something I have is what I think it is, I can't figure out exactly what to say.

> これは梅じゃないの? (Rising intonation)
>
> Is this not a plum?
>
> これは梅じゃないね。(Falling intonation)
>
> This isn't a plum, right?

How could I say something like

> "This isn't a plum?!" (With a sense of surprise)
>
> "Isn't this a plum?"

[For a different example, here is the following from よつばと.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg3Av.png)

[Which is translated officially to this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKnIc.png)

In my mind, the translation is "Aren't I dead?" I guess I don't know if I'm being semantic or not, sorry.

Comment: how about 「これは梅ではないのか?」

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanatory text in brackets also to the first English explanation. I didn't understand the what the difference between the 1st ("Is this not a plum?") and the 3rd ("This isn't a plum?!" (With a sense of surprise)). Based on the above, I think the Japanese translation you gave to the 1st English one would fit well to the 3rd English sentence (i.e. I think that [This isn't a plum?!" (With a sense of surprise)] could be translated as ["これは梅じゃないの? (Rising intonation)"]

Comment: Edited.

Also, to me, the difference between the 1st and 3rd to me is that in the 1st sentence, someone just said that isn't a plum, but you are 100% sure it is, so you are kind of incredulous that someone could think it isn't a plum. The 3rd one is more like it looked like a plum but when you picked it up, you realized it was a bun and you are super surprised. I hope that makes it more clear?

Comment: Yes, now it makes more sense also to a non-native speaker like me. While not being native in Japanese either, I would now say that the translation you gave to the 1st one may not so much stress that you are 100% sure you are right. If wanting to stress more and/or be a bit more confrontative, one could say eg. "これは梅じゃないっておっしゃってますか。" (asking not "is this not a plum?" but rather confirming "So, you are saying this is not a plum?". Similarly for the 3rd one, if the idea was to just express you found out yourself, and got surprised, maybe more natural to say e.g. "なんだ...これは梅じゃなかったんだ!"

Comment: え、梅じゃない？！ and これは梅だろう？ would be my two for the last two, but I don't think that's what you are looking for. ^^;;;